# Sprite-kit: Moving an element in circular path

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying make an element move by the edge of circle.

- I have created and positioned a circle in the middle of the screen:

```swift
var base = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 200 ) // Size of Circle
base.position = CGPointMake(frame.midX, frame.midY)  
base.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
base.glowWidth = 1.0
base.fillColor = UIColor(hue:1, saturation:0.76, brightness:0.94, alpha:1)
base.zPosition = 0
self.addChild(base)
```

- Then I've created another sprite and added an action on it:

```swift
main = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
main.xScale = 0.15
main.yScale = 0.15
main.zPosition = 1
let circle = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake((self.frame.width/2) - 200, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 200,400, 400), cornerRadius: 200)
let circularMove = SKAction.followPath(circle.CGPath, duration: 5.0)
main.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(circularMove,count: 2))
self.addChild(main)
```

The first rotation(see image below) of the spaceship follow exactly the edges of the circle but the second iteration changes the position of the spaceship and move it outside the screen bounds.
Is this normal or am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Sahbi. I want to ask you one question how we can add two or more spaceship? That will move along the circle. Please refer a link or any idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[+ follow:duration:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417822-follow) produce the same effect as [follow:asOffset:orientToPath:duration:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417662-follow) with both, `asOffset` and `orientToPath` parameters set to `true`.

About asOffset parameter from the docs:

> If true, the points in the path are relative offsets to the node’s
>   starting position. If false, the points in the node are absolute
>   coordinate values.

So, you should explicitly set it to false:

```
let circularMove = SKAction.follow(circle.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, duration: 5)
```

Comment: I think you mean `false` in your answer :D