# Repeat SKAction starting position changes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction, cgpath

I've got a path and a SKShapeNode and would like to have the SKShapeNode follow the path forever (Hexagon shape).

```
let pathHexagon:SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode()
let player:SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode()

pathHexagon.path = playerHexagonPath(pathHexRadius)
pathHexagon.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(frame))
pathHexagon.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
pathHexagon.lineWidth = 5
addChild(pathHexagon)

player.path = playerPath(playerSize)
player.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(frame))
player.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
player.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor()
addChild(player)

let action = SKAction.followPath(playerHexagonPath(pathHexRadius), speed: CGFloat(300.0))
player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
```

It works somewhat but the starting position changes every cycle:

http://recordit.co/lEcLxs4DoD

Why is this happening?

Eventually I would like to link this animation to user input. As practice I am trying to replicate Super Hexagon. So if you know a better approach for this please let me know as well.

Comment: You have to use 
[+ followPath:asOffset:orientToPath:speed:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/followPath:asOffset:orientToPath:speed:) method and set `offset` parameter to `false`. Calling the `+ followPath: speed:` method is equivalent to calling the `followPath:asOffset:orientToPath:speed:` method, and passing in `true` to both the `offset` and `orient` parameters.

Comment: Similar answer I've posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35991232/3402095)

Comment: @Whirlwind Thanks. That indeed causes it to no longer shift every cycle. However it now moves somewhere off-screen (to the left-down corner). So the starting position seems wrong now. Disabling player.position has no effect.

Comment: I don't know how rest of your code looks like. Also I don't have time to try your example right now, but if you can edit your question so I can just copy and paste it to reproduce the issue, I might be able to help later.

Comment: Thank you for your trouble: I've uploaded it to GitHub: https://github.com/farayman3/HexagonPractice

Comment: It is just empty SpriteKit project without any custom code :)

Comment: First time using GitHub as well, let me check ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107411/discussion-between-whirlwind-and-secondlemon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `asOffset` parameter does:

> @param asOffset If YES, the points in the path are relative offsets to
>   the node’s starting position. If NO, the points in the node are absolute
>   coordinate values.

So from my understanding, when we set it to false, the points from the path are absolute coordinate values in coordinate system of node's parent.

You can do two things to make it work:

1) To make a container and add a player to it

2) To change scene's anchor point, but I doubt this suits you because you will have to re-position everything.

Probably there are few more ways to solve this, but I haven't tried by myself.

Option 1:

```
  let container = SKNode()
  player.path = playerPath(playerSize)
  player.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
  player.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
  player.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor()
  container.addChild(player)
  container.position = CGPoint(x:frame.midX, y:frame.midY)
  addChild(container)

  let action = SKAction.followPath(pathHexagon.path!, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: CGFloat(300.0))
  player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
```

Or, the option two:

```
self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:0.5)

 mainHexagon.path = hexagonPath(mainHexRadius)
 mainHexagon.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
 mainHexagon.lineWidth = 10
 addChild(mainHexagon)

 pathHexagon.path = playerHexagonPath(pathHexRadius)
 pathHexagon.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
 pathHexagon.lineWidth = 5
 addChild(pathHexagon)

 player.path = playerPath(playerSize)
 player.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
 player.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
 player.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor()
 addChild(player)

 let action = SKAction.followPath(pathHexagon.path!, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: CGFloat(300.0))
 player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
```